# Referencing objects to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I'm unsure how I go about referencing objects to my arraylist.

The class where im declaring the arraylist:

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you explain in words what you are trying to do here `Student student = new Student(Student.name);
  studentList.add(student.Student(name, tmaMark));`

Comment: When you're instantiating a new student, you should be writing: new Student ("Bob"); that is, passing in the name you want to use. You can't reference the class variable name, which is defined as "private String name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `name` is not static so you can not access it as `Student.name` only instance of student can access it if it's `public`.Now, you want to construct the `Student` than you should pass the `name` of student in constructor.You can declare [`getter` *and* `setter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) methods for your `Student` attributes.

Moreover [`ArrayList.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) can be used to add your `Students` to your `list` and you better not add students in constructor use different method to write this scenario.

***FOR EXAMPLE :***

```
Student student = new Student("NewStudent");
System.out.println("Name of student :" +student.getName());
studentList.add(student);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm constantly getting confused with Java but that actually really simplified things and made me realise how bad my previous attempt was!

Comment: @erpel your welcm. :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding:

```
public TutorGroup() {
  super();
  Student student = new Student(Student.name); // this makes no sense
  studentList.add(student.Student(name, tmaMark));
}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `new Student(Student.name)` since it isn't clear what this code is trying to do, but regardless, the compiler is right -- it shouldn't exist, and so get rid of it.

Delete this TutorGroup constructor and re-do it. How you re-do it will depend on where your TutorGroup is to get the Student objects. If they're going to be packed into an ArrayList and then passed in, then give TutorGroup's constructor an `ArrayList<Student>` parameter, and when calling the class, pass in the list. If you will add Students one at a time, then make the constructor simple (or get rid of it), and give the TutorGroup class an addStudent method:

```
public void addStudent(Student s) {
   studentList.add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your TutorGroup constructor your trying to pass the value in the name variable in the Student class which you cant access because 1. The name variable is private so only members of the class have access to it. and 2. It doesn't hold a value yet since that's what your trying to pass into the Student constructor.

What you should do is pass a string literal into your Student constructor like: new Student("Jamie") then it will be saved in the name variable in your Student class, and if you need to access the name later add a public method in your Student class that returns the value in your name variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues.

Firstly the Student class should have some getter methods, so that you can access the data from a student object:

```
public String getName() {
   return this.name;
}

public int getTmaMark() {
   return this.tmaMark;
}
```

For creating a student object with the correct data, you have 2 options:

Option A) Create a constructor for Student that takes both values:

```
public Student(String aName, int aMark)
{
   super();
   this.name = aName;
   this.tmaMark = aMark;       
}
```

Option B) Create setters for your Student class

```
public void setName(String aName) {
   this.name = aName;
}

public void setTmaMark(int aMark) {
   this.tmaMark = aMark;
}
```

You can, of course, implement both options in `Student`, giving you extra flexibility.

Then, to add a new Student to your ArrayList, you can simply create a student and use the array's `add` method:

Examples:

```
ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

// Create student using constructor
Student studentA = new Student("Alice", 15);   

// Create student using setters
Student studentB = new Student();
studentB.setName("Bob");
studentB.setTmaMark(10);

// Add both students to the ArrayList
studentList.add(studentA);
studentList.add(studentB);
```

Please remeber that for the `studentB` example, if you added a constructor with arguments to your `Student` class (Option A) you also need to create an explicit default constructor (without arguments).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what you are trying to do. I am going to assume you want to add a student into the ArrayList called student list. The line `Student student = new Student(Student.name);` is creating a new object of type Student called student but you are not passing into any parameters into the constructor for the student class, but it requires a String which is used as the name. What you want to do (i think) is add a student to your array list. As your ArrayList has type student the method to add student x should be

```
public void addStudent(Student x)
    {
    studentList.add(x);
    }
```

Where Student x is passed as a paramater to the addStudent method. To Create a new student with the object name newstu and the name nameOfStu you could do this.

```
Student newstu = new Student(nameOfStu);
addStudent(newstu);
```

I hope this helps.